# Tableview: Add a shadow

Tags: uitableview, uikit

My designer asked me to add a shadow to the cell of my tableview like this:

[image]

Currently I have implemented everything functional, even the Top | Latest header-view. How can I add such a shadow to the end of each tableviewsection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is my solution. In this situation don't forget to set your view's `backgroundColor` even it's `whiteColor` and `shadowOpacity`.
And give an extra space around your `cellSubView` to show the shadow.
You can set appropriate values instead of mines depending on your requirements.
Hope this helps.

```
cellSubView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
cellSubView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
cellSubView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
cellSubView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,10);
cellSubView.layer.shadowRadius = 3;
```

Comment: I added this in awakeFromNib() but it doesn't change anything? My tableview has a space of 8 points to its superview

Comment: Not your `tableView` should have space around it, but your each `tableViewCell` should have space around it. I suggest adding some `UIView` object as a `subView` to your `cell` and then use my above code for shadowing to this `view`.